# Grails: mobile version of a controller

Tags: grails, controller

I am wondering if you have tried to make a mobile version of a controller?

Right now I am extending GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper with my custom MobileDecoratorMapper which applies layout.mobile.gsp if the mobile phone is detected and I would like to do something similar for some controllers. My idea is to check in the filter if there existing a mobile version of a controller (for example SomethingControllerMobile or SomethingController.mobile.groovy) and if so redirect to it instead of a default SomethingController.

The reason for that is I would like to avoid a lot of if/else statements inside controller itself to check whether it is mobile, and if so do something differently - i do not want spaghetti code.

Does it makes sense to you and if so have you tried to do something similar and what was your approach? The only thing that comes to my mind is check for files in the filter but it does not look like a proper solution, i think this should be possible to be done on urlmapping level, where on the basis of the url grails decides which controller to invoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Spring Mobile plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-mobile) allows you to conditionally execute controller code for mobile devices in a fairly elegant fashion

```
def list = {
  def view = "list"
  withMobileDevice {
        // mobile-specific logic goes here, in this simplistic example we
        // just change the view, but you can do anything you like....
        view = "mobileList"
  }
 render(view: view, model: [list: listInstance])
}
```

Comment: thanks! but what I am particular interested in is to have a different logic for a controller, not different html for a view. I handle the view part by checking user-agent and extending layout decorator so I can load separate CSS and JS for a mobile and this is all I need. So basically I would like to have something very similar what it is here but on the filter level and instead of saying which view to render I would like to specify which controller i would invoke. Alternatively I could specify which action I would invoke - for example list or listMobile. Does it make sense?

Comment: @mkk you can put mobile-specific logic inside the `withMobileDevice` closure, it's not restricted to just changing the view (see my comment in the code above)

Comment: ahh ok - right. The downside I can see is that it uses wurfl and we would like to avoid that, that is why we created our own method to detect mobile phones based on user agent ( yes yes i know it can be modified - not a problem for us). The whole logic is in the service and it returns true / false - whether it is a mobile or not. Do you think it would be easy to apply to this plugin instead of using deviceResolver = wurfl?

Comment: I had a quick look at the source code of the plugin, it seems liek it will be very easy for you to add your own detection method to it. You simply need to make your detection class implement the `org/springframework/mobile/device/DeviceResolver` interface and make the `deviceResolver` Spring bean an instance of this class. If you need any more help, get in touch.

Comment: thanks Don - indeed it seems to be an easy thing to do. I will try this